# Using python to automate the creation of excel reports

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-access

So I'm about to start a project automating the creation of financial reports. I wanted to see if anyone was doing anything similar or had some advice on best practices as I get started.

**Scope:**
Each Quarter our group put together between 250 and 600 Custom Excel reports all by hand. We use various data sources like PDFs, mainframe data, other excel workbooks, word documents just to name a few.  The work is about 80% manual entry looking over other reports for the figure we need and then physically entering them in an excel workbook.  20% of the data is imported from the mainframe using Excel's Data source links and other SAS reports

**Problems:**
Every single report is different :(  However I have identified about 14 or so "similar structures" for all of the reports.  The differences come from how the compy we report to want their reports to show.

It takes an average of 30 days to put a report together.  It is so crucial they are 100% accurate the finished work passes through 4 to 5 other people before it is signed off on and ready to send to clients.

The idea is to create a system to "map" each report.  The map will show what each cell is supposed to contain.  If it contains a manually entered value than where the value is located and how it is broken out. Then let the program go find that value for each quarter's report and use the map for the new report.   Or if there is a formula or mainframe call then the map will store the info the call needs to get the current info off the mainframe, though the excel workbook already has this information stored in the cell.

Ultimately I want to use these maps to build a new report for new clients which takes 3 months to do now.

I think using python to do this might be best, but I Could also use VBA, or I'm even open to learning yet another programming language

I would love to hear from anyone who might have ideas on the best way to accomplish this.  If I can get permission perhaps I can upload a test report for review. if I can't I'll create a dummy report.  I currently don't have any code written for this

Comment: This seems like a project requirement rather than a question. It's always better to show some minimal effort `in code` - so other people can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some great tools to help integrate Python and Excel. The challenges you face are quite obviously with the manual entries. If they can be streamlined into input streams like a database or Excel files that get queried and your reports collate from those sources there may be potential to get some advantage.

xlwings https://www.xlwings.org/ is fantastic. It facilitates a two-way communication between Python and Excel. You still need to write code but in the case of xlwings it could be either VBA or Python.

If your reports require defining calculations and workings, like a business case or some financial model, where the definition of the calculation needs to be auditable by non-coders, you may want to consider FlyingKoala https://github.com/bradbase/flyingkoala (which uses xlwings and other libraries).  Disclaimer: I wrote FlyingKoala and it is still quite young, but it is designed for customized numerical modelling intending to reduce the amount of Python that gets written.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into these.  The issue as you stated is going to be non-coders do need to update and create new maps and edit old ones as specifications change.

Comment: xlwings, PyXll, DataNitro and FlyingKoala are all useful for this. Each has their own quirk.

PyXll has a lot of menu integration.

FlyingKoala requires someone write some code, but then integrates reasonably easily. Here's a worked example https://flyingkoala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worked_example_horticulture.html